# Unfortunately, Your app has stopped -Android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have just compiled the hello world program intially provided by android

log

```
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): Process: com.example.helloandroid2, PID: 1933
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloandroid2/com.example.helloandroid2.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.example.helloandroid2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
09-11 12:02:39.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: `You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.`

Comment: Use API level 19 and platform 4.4.2 everything works fine and change theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"`

Comment: <uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="15"
   android:targetSdkVersion="19" />